# How to configure drush command-specific archive-dump --tar-options in a site alias

Tags: drush

The following command does exactly what I want — It dumps an archive, excluding all of the files and directories that I don't want:

```
$ drush archive-dump --tar-options="--exclude=.git --exclude=*.psd --exclude=sites/default/files/styles/ --exclude=sites/default/files/private/backup_migrate/manual/"
```

Can anyone show me how to set these extra `command-specific` `archive-dump` `tar-options` inside a site-alias array in `aliases.drushrc.php`?

I've tried every variation I can think of, but I can't seem to get the syntax right.

**Update** Here is a [gist with my full test setup](https://gist.github.com/zachharkey/ab49461d30775906e823) including verbose output and -debug info.

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this - Edit: I've just confirmed that the following works as expected with Drush 6.3:

```php
$aliases['example.com'] = array(
  'uri' => 'example.com',
  'root' => '/var/www/example.com/public_html',
  'command-specific' => array (
    'archive-dump' => array (
      'tar-options' => '--exclude=directory1 --exclude=sites/all/modules --exclude=*.txt',
    ),
  ),
);
```

I did notice that %files didn't work (Warning: `sprintf(): Too few arguments exec.inc:138`).

Comment: This doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I've just confirmed that this example works with Drush 6.3. Do you get an error? Maybe try with --debug option?

Comment: I was using Drush 6.2, So I upgraded to 6.3 and started with a fresh Drupal install and a site alias closely matching your example. It still isn't working for me. 

Here is a [gist with my full test setup](https://gist.github.com/zachharkey/ab49461d30775906e823) including verbose output and -debug info.